# construct an object of B in constructor of class A

Tags: c++, gcc

Here is what I am trying to do, I want the class A's constructor to call B's constructor for an object of B, like this main()->A->B

A.cpp:(included B.h)

```
A::A(){
  B foo;
}
```

B.h:

```
class B{
 B(){//some code};
};
```

but GCC won't compile and says ***A::B foo has initializer but incomplete type***. I am guessing the compiler saw no local class of B defined in A, so it complained and didn't know the Class B was from another file. My question is how to construct an B's object in A's constructor like above.I am sure I am missing some fundamentals about C++, please bear with me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try a forward define before class A `class B;` which just tells the compiler you will define it later

Comment: That will not allow you to create an instance of the class. In fact, it will cause a warning much like the one Clint is getting. That is assuming you are saying what I think. Are you suggesting to type `class B;` before the definition of `A::A`?

Comment: @DavidStone I was - but without seeing full code it is hard to see the real problem - it was just a quick guess at the OP's issue

Comment: well, that lead to my real question, I wanted to construct an object of B in the main, and pass a pointer to it to the following construction of A in main, then store the pointer in A. However, if I forward declaration for B in A, the pointer I have in A would be A::B*, the but one I passed in is just B*, I can't do this A::B* = B*, even though I think they are the same. Thanks!

Comment: @ClintHui Best thing to do is provide a complete simplified example that shows you exact code - one source file is best - but not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any class of type `A::B`. From your comment, it looks like you are trying to use a pointer to `B` by calling it `A::B *`. This is incorrect. A pointer to `B` is always `B *`, regardless of where it appears. From what you said, it looks like you want something like this:

a.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP_
#define A_HPP_

class B;
class A {
public:
    A(B * b);
private:
    B * my_very_own_b;
};

#endif    // A_HPP_
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

A::A(B * b):
    my_very_own_b(b)
    {
}
```

b.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP_
#define B_HPP_

class B {
public:
    B();
private:
    int x;
};

#endif    // B_HPP_
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.hpp"
B::B():
    x(0)
    {
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right on! Forward Declaration solved the problem! I forward declared the class B inside the scope of A, that's why I got A::B* pointer, it should be outside the scope of A in the global. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();  // Don't define A::A() here
              // As the compiler has not seen B
};
class B
{
    public:
        B() {}
};
// At this point both classes have been seen
A::A()
{
    ::B foo;  // So now you can use B
              // Note I am using ::B here
              //      As the error message suggests that you have some class B defined
              //      Within A which is confusing it. the prefix :: means take the class
              //      B from the global scope rather than a closer scope.
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried that, but B is not in global scope, see my comments above, that's why the compiler confused I think. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your problem is trying to explain in English (which is not an exact language). Show the code that you are using rather than trying to explain the code you are using.

Comment: Yea, I could have done that, but the code is too messy. Thanks for the headsup